# Text align right with icon menu action bar sherlock

Tags: android, user-interface, drop-down-menu, actionbarsherlock

I've a problem with menu option. I'm using action bar sherlock, when i'm clicking the option menu, the text align on the left side.
I want my text of option menu align on right side with a icon first.

the idea:
[image]
Here is the option menu code:

```
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        // TWEAK: FC when inflated from XML
        searchItem = (MenuItem) menu.add(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_search));
        searchItem.setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_search);
        searchItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        // Create the SearchView
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        // Collapse when focus lost
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
                if(hasFocus) {
                    mListener.OnSearchClickListener();
                } else {
                    searchItem.collapseActionView();
                }
            }
        });
        // Assign the SearchView to the menuItem
        searchItem.setActionView(searchView);
        final Context ct = getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext();
        SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Action Item");
        subMenu1.add("Sample").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
//              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlaceActivity.class);
//              startActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
        subMenu1.add("Sample2").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                Intent i = new Intent(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(), FragmentPagerSupport.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
            }
        });
        subMenu1.add("Map").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                FChangeView();
                return false;
            }
        });
        //blabla
        subMenu1.add("Help").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
//              mMapFragment.FNearMe();
                return false;
            }
        });
        subMenu1.add("Current Location").setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
//              mMapFragment.FCurrentLocation();
                return false;
            }
        });
        MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);       
    }
```

any idea for me?
 it's pleasure if has a code example

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with simple ActionBar or ActionBarSherlock. You will have to instead handle the menu item click yourself and show a [ListPopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html). Provide the `ListPopupWindow` an adapter that displays the items as you've described, just as you would with any ListView.